# How to use CASE statement in FROM Clause to decide which table to be used for fetching data in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables , HISTORY_DATA and CURRENT_DATA , I have an input parameter REPORT_DATE ,as per following  Condition , I have to fetch data :

```
IF(REPORT_DATE<=TRUNC(SYSDATE-40))THEN
         SCHD_TABLE:='HISTORY_DATA' ;
         ELSE
         SCHD_TABLE:='CURRENT_DATA';  
         END IF ;
```

1. I tried using dynamic SQL , but it is giving error as invalid table name .

   ```
   SELECT * FROM ''||SCHD_TABLE||'' ;
   ```
2. Used CASE STATEMENT but it also gave Syntax error :

   ```
   SELECT * FROM (CASE WHEN REPORT_DATE<=TRUNC(SYSDATE-40) THEN HISTORY_DATA 
                       ELSE CURRENT_DATA 
                  END)
   ```

Please guide how to resolve this .

Comment: If you are using dynamic SQL, I expect to see `execute immediate`.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is where you use PL/SQL to write a new string with a new SQL Statement in it, then use `execute` to execute teat string.  You can't just run a string *(that's what `execute` is for)`, you can't just substitute a string directly into a static sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a function that returns refcursor. Here's an example.

First, sample tables:

```
SQL> create table history_data as
  2    select deptno, ename, job from emp where deptno = 10;

Table created.

SQL> create table current_data as
  2    select deptno, ename, job from emp where deptno = 20;

Table created.
```

Function returns data depending on `par_report_date`:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_report_date in date)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    if par_report_date <= trunc(sysdate) - 40 then
  7       open rc for select * from history_data;
  8    else
  9       open rc for select * from current_data;
 10    end if;
 11    return rc;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Testing (history data):

```
SQL> select f_test(date '2021-02-15') history_data from dual;

HISTORY_DATA
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        10 MILLER     CLERK
```

Testing (current data):

```
SQL> select f_test(sysdate) current_data from dual;

CURRENT_DATA
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        20 SMITH      CLERK
        20 JONES      MANAGER
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST
        20 ADAMS      CLERK
        20 FORD       ANALYST


SQL>
```

---

Based on your comment (about *dynamic SQL*): I'm not sure what benefit you expect from it. Yes, you can "concatenate" appropriate table name to the `select` statement, but the outcome is just the same. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_report_date in date)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(200);
  5    rc    sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    l_str := 'select * from ' ||
  8             case when par_report_date <= trunc(sysdate) - 40 then 'history_data'
  9                  else 'current_data'
 10             end;
 11    open rc for l_str;
 12    return rc;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(date '2021-02-15') history_data from dual;

HISTORY_DATA
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        10 MILLER     CLERK


SQL>
```

Comment: Lie to you?  Okay...  Croatia will win the Euros ;)

Comment: Sir thanks but can you also tell if this can be done through dynamic SQL the way I did

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more code; have a look.

Comment: No problem, @radha.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `history_data` and `current_data` have equivalent columns, you can use `UNION ALL` and two queries. Each query `SELECT`s everything from a table if and only if the condition depending on you variable in the `WHERE` clause is true. Since the conditions in the `WHERE` clauses are negations of each other, one query will return an empty set when the other returns something. So you'll only get the result from the table you want according to your condition.

```
SELECT *
       FROM history_data
       WHERE report_date <= trunc(sysdate - 40)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
       FROM current_data
       WHERE report_date > trunc(sysdate - 40);
```

And by the way, it's a `CASE` **expression** not a statement you have there.

Comment: Sir this solution doesn't work for me as Data stored in HISTORY Table is huge , approximately 20-30 crores of records  while in CURRENT DATA , it is not more than 30 lakh records , so I want to fetch data from HISTORY DATA only after  report_date <= trunc(sysdate - 40) is satisfied

Comment: @radha: As I wrote nothing is selected from the table where the condition isn't true, so `history_data` is only touched when `report_date <= trunc(sysdate - 40)` which is exactly what you asked for, i.e. this does work for you.

Comment: My bad ! I misread , got the point now , Thanks